# How to use MFC Project methods in win32 Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have two projects.

1. MFC project
2. Win32 Project.

My main project is win32 project. But I have 2 methods which are very important in MFC project. I tried to add those two methods in my win32 project. I am unable to do it. So please help me.

Thanku.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DLL and add those methods in the DLL and access it in both MFC and WIn32 projects

Comment: I'l create dll file for MFC project. But Please tell me how to use this dll in win32 project.

Comment: @user1258896 : http://www.functionx.com/visualc/libraries/win32dll.htm and also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6351/Regular-DLL-Tutor-For-Beginners